# python's exec() works oddly inside functions

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I (think I) need `exec()` to procedurally define variables for symbolic computation. The code searches for variables in an expression like 'x/y + z' and generates three variables,
`x = sp.sympy('x')`, `y = sp.sympy('y')`, `z = sp.sympy('z')`(for example).

When I run the code

```
for char in expr:
    if char.isalpha():
        exec('%s = sp.symbols("%s")' % (char, char))
        print(type(char))
```

It works just as it should. `print(type(char))` just checks if what I wanted to happen happens (it prints `<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>` if it worked).

However, as I need this for a general `expr`, I need this inside a function. When I do this `print(type(char))` outputs `<class 'str'>`, which means it didn't work.

Also, if I type `print(type(char))` inside the exec I get a correct output.

Note: I know `exec()` is dangerous. I'm just going to use this to have an easier time writing lab reports.

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow. If there's anything I should change to keep up with the page's etiquette please let me know.

Comment: I'm actually surprised the first time it worked and where's why. `char` is a string. If you put this inside an `exec`, then you are doing type of the actual variable and not `char`. Keep in mind that you are storing `x` as <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>. I think what you did was `type(x)` in your exec() and not `type(char)`

Comment: Oh yeah you're absolutle right, I didn't change `char` at all. So if instead of `type(char)` I used `type(x)` it should work?

Comment: Within the if statement you can do: `exec('print(type(%s))' % char)`

Comment: If that answer the question, I can create my final answer below.

Comment: @astrochun It didn't, sorry. If `char = 'x'`, and inside the for loop I've got print(type(x)) that should print `<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>`, but it says x is not defined.

Comment: >Within the if statement you can do: `exec('print(type(%s))' % char)`, yeah, and it works, but only inside the `exec()`, so outside of it the variable `char` (x, y or whatever) is not defined.

Comment: See below for a solution. You might find it beneficial to do it as a dict. I can post a solution for that as well. Though since I don't have the rest of your code, I'm not sure how you use these namespace given that you are using the `exec` function instead of defining individual variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't think of a way to get it into one line, but I believe this will work:

```
for char in expr:
    if char.isalpha():
        exec('%s = sp.symbols("%s")' % (char, char))
        exec('temp_type = type(%s)' % char) 
        print(temp_type)
```

Alternatively using a `dict` approach may make it easier in the long run. It avoids the `exec`.

```
symbol_dict = dict()
for char in expr:
    if char.isalpha():
        symbol_dict[char] = sp.symbols(char)
        print(symbol_dict[char])
```

Comment: Yes, as I said, the expression works cool outside of functions. It doesn't inside of them, for some reason. Edit, you're right. I don't know what's different. Thanks a lot!! I was losing my mind over this stupid problem that I'm goint to use like once in my life.

Comment: The `dict` approach could have avoiding losing your mind. I will edit my post. It avoids using `exec` and might be beneficial down the road if you want to pass a dict into another function.

Comment: What I do not understand is that, if `expr = 'x'`, why when I use `print(x)` after the for but inside the function, I get that `x` is not defined.

Comment: Okay! I will be waiting.

Comment: See revision. Yea, I'm not sure about that either. I see what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. The problem is that I need the variables, because the output of the function I want it to be a numerical function `f`, defined with a structure like `exec('f = sp.lambdify(%s, %s))' % (variables, expr))`, because to use lambdify I need to define the input variables of the function. I may have a flaw in my understanding of lambdify or something that makes what I want to do easier.